# Is NH3 a strong ligand or weak?

Tags: coordination-compounds

Sometimes it produces high spin complex and sometimes low one. Is there any generalised result

Answer (score 2):

$\ce{NH3}$ is roughly in the middle of the spectrochemical series as it is only a $\sigma$-donor, so it can kind of though as to create splitting energy that isn't large or small. But instead other factors will play more of a role in deciding the size of energy split such as oxidation state, coordination number and whether it is a 3d, 4d or 5d metal.